# GCP SDK credentials error : "Could not load the default credentials"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

`enter code here`[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuM1a.png)

I'm trying to pass GCP credentials (Service account key JSON file) to GCP SDK. GCP documentation suggests 2 ways to do it:

- Using environmental variable
- Passing using code (I deleted the environmental variable to test this)

First one is working fine. But I want to pass the credentials via code as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

The document says to point out to path where the key is located like below given snippet, but I'm getting error as "Could not load the default credentials".

Here is the snippet of what I tried in my code:

```js
const monitoring = require('@google-cloud/monitoring');
const client = new monitoring.AlertPolicyServiceClient({projectID: "my-project-id",keyFilename:"key path.json"});
```

Am I missing out anything important here? Please advise on this.

Comment: Your question lacks detail and is likely going to be closed. Please, at least include the link to your "exactly as suggested" reference.

Comment: If you're refering to [this](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html) then you need to name the parameters: `new Storage({
  projectId: 'your-project-id',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});`

Comment: Where are you running this code? If a Google Cloud compute service (Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Functions, etc), then you do not need the service account JSON key file at all - use credentials from metadata. Edit your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm running this code from my application which makes a API call to Google cloud to fetch information.  So in order to fetch these information I had to use service account and its key. But the credentials aren't getting loaded. Please advise.

Comment: You did not answer where you are running the code. Note: the parameters to **new Storage()** are not correct. Consult the SDK documentation.

Comment: @JohnHanley For now I'm running this code locally but planning to deploy it in EC2 instances of AWS. Code snippet which I've added here is from GCP documentation and I'm passing the parameters exactly same way. I've also added the link of doumentation. where I got this information from.

Comment: You have had two people with extensive Google Cloud experience tell you that the parameters are wrong. Please look up the API in the documentation instead of referring to a screenshot that happens to be misleading. For example to specify a service account JSON key file, use this **const storage = new Storage({keyFilename: 'key.json'});**. When in doubt review the source code: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/src/storage.ts The API is here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Storage.html review **StorageOptions** which are key: value pairs.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. I've added my code snippet. Still it doesnt work... @JohnHanley

Comment: Update your question with what you tried.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated the code snippet in my  question.

Comment: What is the error message with the new code?

Comment: @JohnHanley When I try running the API call.. It says "Could not load default credentials"... If i remove these parameters (path and project ID) and set the environmental variable with the path of json file located then it works well and good.  I don't want to store my json key in env variable as its not safe.. So my idea is to save them in aws secrets manager from there I want to fetch it and use it in my application. For this reason I'm trying to check if passing credentials via code works but It is not happening..